# consistent estimation of quantiles (without overlapping quantiles)

Tags: forecasting, quantile-regression, multivariate-regression

I would like to forecast quantile ranges. The observations are assumed to be heteroscedastic. Mostly, I am confronted with the problem that quantile regression results for different quantiles do overlap for a subset of observations (lower quantile > higher quantile), which is not acceptable for the application usage I have in mind. Do you know a procedure or maybe even an implementation which consistently estimate different quantiles so that they do not overlap?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a [CRAN package:quantregGrowth](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregGrowth/quantregGrowth.pdf) (with which I have no experience).  This is also a much discussed problem in the literature, see [this stored search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=DkT&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk029dSBz3bsu8MtnzuQjXEXhXyXsRQ%3A1614613830995&ei=Rg09YPabPLm85OUP5u6auAs&q=joint+estimation+of+multiple+quantiles+with+quantile+regression&oq=joint+estimation+of+multiple+quantiles+with+quantile+regression&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgjECc6AggAOgIILjoECAAQQzoECC4QQzoFCAAQywE6BggAEBYQHjoGCAAQDRAeOggIABAIEA0QHjoICCEQFhAdEB46CAgAEBYQChAeOgUIIRCgAToECCEQFToHCCEQChCgAToECCEQClD65wFYu_ICYKL5AmgCcAB4AIAB5gGIAZgvkgEHNTEuMTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj21uGeuY_vAhU5HrkGHWa3BrcQ4dUDCAw&uact=5).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known problem of quantile regression.

Your best bet is to forecast full predictive densities, then extract the quantiles of interest from the predictive density at each future time point.

Unfortunately, standard forecasting methods like ARIMA or ETS do not model heteroskedasticity. Depending on your application, you may want to look at (G)ARCH, or perhaps at methods that account for heteroskedasticity and can be made to work for time series, like negative binomial regression.

Comment: This dose not sound right to me: "Your best bet is to forecast full predictive densities". There is no unbiased predictor of the PDF, unless there is some reasonable ground for expecting a particular distribution. By contrast, the CDF is predictable with good error bounds, by the Kolmogorov-Smirnov theorem. Quantiles are particular points on the CDF.

Comment: @chrishmorris: I am not familiar with the Kolmogorov–Smirnov theorem, can you point me to a reference? If you disagree with my proposal, would you be interested in posting an alternative approach the OP could use?

Comment: http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/Kolmogorov-Smirnov.pdf. The Glivenko–Cantelli Theorem showed convergence in probability, and Kolmogorov proved the rate of convergence. There is a good chapter on it in Statistical Learning Theory by Vapnik.